# Catch output of lua_error()?

Tags: error-handling, lua

Currently I'm using lua out of an console application, means whenever there is an error in script and `lua_error()` is called, the related text it is printed.

Now I have to move that thingy into a GUI-application that runs without a console in background. Error text that appear have to be submitted to the main application so that it is able to do whatever is necessary with it. As a second point the whole application has NOT to be stopped (like it happened for the console-application).

So my question: Is there a possibility to catch the error messages given with `lua_error()` at some point in code for further processing and to avoid the application is stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Lua manua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.3)l points out, you will want to use protected calls for executing the Lua code from your application. If you encounter an error from an unprotected call, Lua will call a panic function, which writes the error output to the console that you wanted to get rid of.

In particular, [lua_pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall) may be provided with a custom message handler that is invoked in case of an error. You could provide a custom handler that interacts with your GUI.

Be aware though that message handlers are invoked via a C-longjmp, which has [certain implications](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.6) on what you can and can not do from within a message handler.

Alternatively, don't provide a message handler at all and instead check the return value of the `lua_pcall` function. In case of an error, the error message can be retrieved from the top of the Lua stack.

Comment: Another (and I think simpler) way is to check return value of `lua_pcall`. If it's different that 0, the error message is right there on the stack, you just need to get it with `lua_to(l)string`.

Answer (score 0):

`lua_error` by itself does not emit any output: it's the application that called Lua that handles how to report error.

By *console*, I assume you mean you're using the standard Lua command-line interpreter. It seems that you now want to embed Lua into your application. In this case, you use `lua_pcall` to run Lua scripts and check its return value, handling any errors that may happen.